# template-size array initialization in initializer list, C++

Tags: c++, templates

```
class Y; //not really relevant

class B
{
  B(Y*);
  //stuff
}

template<int SIZE> class X : public Y
{
  B array[SIZE];

  X();
}
```

I would like to call constructor of each element of array[] with this as parameter. How can I do that in pretty way? C++14 and even 17 are OK for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of several approaches:

```
template <int SIZE>
class X : public Y
{
    B array[SIZE];

    template <std::size_t>
    X* that() { return this; } // don't abuse the comma operator

    template <std::size_t... Is>
    X(std::index_sequence<Is...>) : array{ that<Is>()... } {}

public:
    X() : X(std::make_index_sequence<SIZE>{}) {}
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d762ca3c3a387118)

Comment: What is `std::make_index_sequence` and `std::index_sequence? I can't find any docs for that but I've found an information somewhere that those are [`std::integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) aliases...

Answer (score 2):

There's no "nice" or simple way of doing it with C arrays (or even `std::array`).

You can to it very easily if you change to use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. It has a [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) that allows you to set the size *and* pass the default value for all elements:

```
template<int SIZE> class X : public Y
{
    std::vector<B> array;

    X()
        : array(SIZE, B(this))
    {}
};
```

Comment: What a shame. I REALLY hate C++, but it's fast so I have to live with it... You could call it marriage of convenience -.-

Comment: @psorek Why are you saying "what a shame"? In C++, you want to avoid arrays anyway whenever possible. To me, he solution of Joachim Pileborg sounds pretty much what you should want.

Comment: I would very much like to avoid dynamic memory allocation as much as possible, becouse of reasons.

Comment: @psorek "Because of reasons" is really no explanation. "Because of a limited heap on an embedded system" is a good reason and explanation.

Comment: This will copy-construct each vector element from a temporary `B(this)`,  not clear if this suits OP's requirements