# C++ template size argument from initalizer list without standard library

Tags: c++, templates

I'm working on some C++ code for an embedded platform (an ATTiny, though I don't think that matters) which miraculously can compile with C++17.  I am trying to use `constexpr` and template arguments anywhere possible in order to avoid managing array sizes manually while also avoiding memory allocations, while also producing something that's difficult to express an invalid state with in case coworkers need to modify it later.

I have a particular data type which needs to be able to store a variable number of values (varies in the source code, not during runtime) which would be iterated through at runtime. Using the template array `constexpr` size trick and a template argument, I can define an array with an initializer list and then pass it to the object being constructed with a template size argument as follows:

```cpp
template <typename T, size_t n> 
constexpr size_t array_size(const T (&)[n]) { return n; }


uint16_t data_fast_flash[] = { 100, 400 };
LedPattern<array_size(data_fast_flash)> fast_flash{data_fast_flash};

uint16_t data_slow_flash[] = { 100, 900 };
LedPattern<array_size(data_slow_flash)> slow_flash{data_slow_flash};

uint16_t data_double_flash[] = { 100, 200, 100, 1000 };
LedPattern<array_size(data_double_flash)> double_flash{data_double_flash};
```

The `LedPattern` class is as follows, though  I'm not sure it's relevant:

```cpp
template <size_t N>
class LedPattern : public ILedPattern {
public:
    explicit LedPattern(uint16_t* delay) : delay_(delay), count_(N) {}

    void reset() override { index_ = 0; };

    [[nodiscard]] uint16_t current() const override { return *(delay_ + index_); }
    void next() override {
        if (++index_ >= count_) index_ = 0;
    };

private:
    uint16_t* delay_;
    size_t count_;
    size_t index_{};
};
```

All of the above works as expected, but I was hoping to compress the definitions to something where the creation and naming of the `uint16_t` arrays could go away, given that I think they're now the most typo-prone part of the setup.

I did find some seemingly related solutions, but they all rely on the standard library, which I don't have on this platform, such as one [using `std::index_sequence`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40082125/template-size-array-initialization-in-initializer-list-c), and another using `std::forward`.

With C++17 but *without* the standard library, is there some way of constructing something functionally similar with templates that would:

1. Only require some sort of initializer list of values
2. Could preferably deduce the number of elements in the value list itself
3. Would not require any allocations at runtime

Something roughly like the following, though I'm not attached to this exact syntax and I have no problem changing how `LedPattern` works internally:

```cpp
LedPattern fast_flash{100, 400};

LedPattern slow_flash{100, 900};

LedPattern double_flash{100, 200, 100, 1000};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a job for [user-defined-deduction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#User-defined_deduction_guides).  You could do something like the following:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>

using std::size_t;
using std::uint16_t;

template<size_t N>
class LedPattern {
public:
    template<typename ...D>
    explicit LedPattern(D...d) : delay_{uint16_t(d)...}, count_(N) {}

private:
    uint16_t delay_[N];
    size_t count_;
    size_t index_{};
};

template<std::convertible_to<uint16_t> ...D>
LedPattern(D...) -> LedPattern<sizeof...(D)>;

LedPattern pat{100, 200, 300};
```

Just replace `std::convertible_to<uint16_t>` with `typename` if your compiler doesn't support concepts yet.

Comment: That seemed to do it!  It's going to take me some time to understand how, but this is a part of the language I never even knew existed.  Thank you!